# Building Mono without using any binaries

Tags: linux, build, mono

I need to build Mono without using any binaries (for CentOS 6). But as I understand, Mono requires working C# compiler and in base build approach it is monolite (minimal **binary** distribution of mcs).

Is there any way to build mcs without mcs? Looks like I need either another C# compiler or ignore 'no-binary' requirement.

Comment: You have to start somewhere when you are boot-strapping a compiler. With a `no-binary' requirement how would you even boot-strap GCC that is needed to compile the Mono runtime?....

Comment: I have some allowed binary list, which includes GCC and some other basic tools/libs. Question is about C# compiler mainly.

Comment: Unless you plan handing coding your own `basic.exe` M/CIL compiler, you have to accept the fact that to boot strap the Mono/.Net framework, you have to have a M/CIL compiler, and in this case it is `basic.exe`. Note: Depending upon how you define binary, basic.exe, might get a "pass" since it is a CIL-based binary.... ;-)

Comment: Looks like this is everything, that I wanted to know. Just to be sure, that 'no-binary' is bad idea there. Now I'll need to persuade colleagues :). Thank you.

Comment: At some point you have to trust something, whether it is GCC, autoconf, automake, the linux kernel, the GNU tools,  etc... so if your group does not trust mono and/or any other binaries that are published from the Mono Project, Xamarin and/or Microsoft then your options are fairly limited...